# For loop not updating the list

Tags: python, list

Main code:

```
for i in Pool:
    print(i)
    while(i[0] != 1):
        print('i is ' + str(i))
        i=rotate(i) 
        print('after rotate i is ' + str(i)) 
print(Pool)
```

Rotate Function:

```
def rotate(a):
    a= a[1:]+a[:1]
    return a
```

Result:

```
[1, 2, 3]
[1, 3, 2]
[2, 1, 3]
i is [2, 1, 3]
after rotate i is [1, 3, 2]
[2, 3, 1]
i is [2, 3, 1]
after rotate i is [3, 1, 2]
i is [3, 1, 2]
after rotate i is [1, 2, 3]
[3, 1, 2]
i is [3, 1, 2]
after rotate i is [1, 2, 3]
[3, 2, 1]
i is [3, 2, 1]
after rotate i is [2, 1, 3]
i is [2, 1, 3]
after rotate i is [1, 3, 2]
[[1, 2, 3], [1, 3, 2], [2, 1, 3], [2, 3, 1], [3, 1, 2], [3, 2, 1]]
```

From this code, Pool = [[1, 2, 3], [1, 3, 2], [2, 1, 3], [2, 3, 1], [3, 1, 2], [3, 2, 1]]

I can see my rotate function works and rotates 3,2,1 to 2,1,3 but it is not updated to the pool. The result I want is [[1, 2, 3], [1, 3, 2], [1, 3, 2], [1, 2, 3], [1, 2, 3], [1, 3, 2]]

Comment: Where is you rotate function?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're creating a new list, rather than rotating it in place.

To rotate a list in place, use `a[:] = a[1:] + a[:1]`; you can then also omit the `return` (and it's probably better style to omit it).

```
def rotate(a):
    """ Rotate the list in-place """
    a[:] = a[1:] + a[:1]
```

You then call this function without using the return value (which will be `None`):

```
for i in Pool:
    while i[0] != 1:
        rotate(i)
```

Comment: Yeah, you need to replace `i=rotate(i)` with just `rotate(i)`

Answer (score 0):

```
    Pool = [[1, 2, 3], [1, 3, 2], [2, 1, 3], [2, 3, 1], [3, 1, 2], [3, 2, 1]]
    
    
    def rotate(a):
        a = a[1:] + a[:1]
        return a
    
    
    new_pool = []
    for i in Pool:
        while i[0] != 1:
            print('i is ' + str(i))
            i = rotate(i)
            print('after rotate i is ' + str(i))
        new_pool.append(i)
    print(Pool)
    print(new_pool)
```

Answer (score -1):

You need to update Pool by using `Pool[index] = i`, I'm guessing after the second loop.
Example:

```
Pool = [[1, 2, 3], [1, 3, 2], [2, 1, 3], [2, 3, 1], [3, 1, 2], [3, 2, 1]]

def rotate(i):
    return i[1:]+i[:1]

print(Pool)
for index,i in enumerate(Pool):
    print(i)
    while (i[0] != 1):
        print('i is ' + str(i))
        i = rotate(i)
        print('after rotate i is ' + str(i))
    Pool[index]  = i
print(Pool)
```

Comment: That's not the only way to do it.